# Can't change ylab in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I create this plot, I realize even I specify ylab, it is not applied to the output plot, whereas other labs works perfectly.
Code below:

```
 saturation = function(po2,L){((po2/5.5)*(1+(po2/5.5))^3+
                                L*(po2/300)*(1+(po2/300))^3)/((1+(po2/5.5))^4+L*(1+(po2/300))^4)} #enter the equation
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

labels = '<p><span style="color: #304d63;">L = 10</span>, 
<span style="color: #b2e7e8;">L = 30</span>, 
<span style="color: #8fb9aa;">L = 100</span>, 
<span style="color: #f2d096;">L = 300</span>, 
<span style="color: #ed8975;">L = 1000</span>, 
<span style="color: #8c695d;">L = 3000</span></p>'
color_scheme = c("#304D63", "#B2E7E8", "#8FB9aa",'#F2D096',"#Ed8975",'#8C695D')
Ls = c(10,30,100,300,1000,3000)

plot = ggplot()+ xlim(0,150)
for(i in 1:6){
  plot = plot + geom_function(fun = saturation,args = list (L= Ls[i]),color = color_scheme[i])

}
plot = plot + labs(title = 'figure 1', xlab = 'pO2',ylab = '%hemeglobin bound',subtitle=(labels))+
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_markdown())

plot
```

and the output is below:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhqWB.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the `labs` function, the argument to label the y axis is called `y`, not `ylab`

```r
plot + 
  labs(title = 'figure 1', x = 'pO2', y = '%hemeglobin bound', 
       subtitle = labels) +
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_markdown())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! That fixed my problem.
I am a little bit confused on why my x-axis label worked in the same line.

Comment: @iRIs normally `labs` is forgiving about what you put in it. Any argument starting with an x or y will be used as the label for that axis, _unless there is already a label for that axis_, in which case it needs to be "x" or "y" to overwrite the existing axis label. `geom_function` seems to add a y axis label as a fallback, but not an x axis label, so `xlab` gets used but `ylab` gets ignored. In any case, it's safer to use `x` and `y`.